# Difference between call() function and calling implicit constructor of inherited class

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between calling a function call(), and calling implicit constructor of a inherited class?

Example1:

```
function DepthRectangle(w, h, d){
    Rectangle.call(this, w, h);
    this.depth = d;
}
```

Example2:

```
function DepthRectangle(w, h, d){
    this = new Rectangle(w, h);
    this.depth = d;
}
```

Constructor of Rectangle:

```
function Rectangle(w, h){
    this.width = w;
    this.height = h;
}
```

Comment: In my opinion this site will kill Facebook. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your second example doesn't work, because the `this` value is not assignable, it isn't a valid *left-hand side* expression for assignments.

But, suppose that you have:

```
function DepthRectangle(w, h, d){
    var obj = new Rectangle(w, h);
    obj.depth = d;
    return obj;
}
```

In this case, the difference would be that the object returned by this function will inherit directly from `Rectangle.prototype`, and not from `DepthRectangle`.

For example, with the above function:

```
//...
DepthRectangle.prototype.inherited = "foo";
Rectangle.prototype.inherited = "bar";

var obj = new DepthRectangle(1,2,3); // note: new is not really needed
obj.inherited; // "bar", from Rectangle.prototype
obj instanceof DepthRectangle; // false
```

In your first example, using the `call` method will just execute the `Rectangle` function, but with the `this` value pointing to the object that was created on `DepthRectangle`, meaning that this object will in fact still inherit from `DepthRectangle.prototype`.

Comment: +1 - cool, but not only is *new* not needed in *new DpethRectangle*, its use is misleading because of the munged inheritance. Better to call the function "creatDepthRectangle" or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Well, for one, assigning `this = new Rectangle(w, h)` will probably throw

`Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

`.call()` basically lets you do the same thing you're wanting to do. It works by allowing you to set the value of `this` within the function you're calling. If you're calling another functions constructor, it will apply to your constructor to your current `this` object.

Mind you, the prototype of `Rectangle` wouldn't be copied in this fashion, and you need to account for that if you want it to be.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/function/call

Answer (score 2):

> What is the difference between calling a function call(), and calling implicit constructor of a inherited class?

There are no implicit constructors in JavaScript.

The code

```
Rectangle.call(this, w, h);
```

...will ensure that within `Rectangle`, `this` refers to the object that `this` refers to in the calling code.

In the code

```
new Rectangle(w, h);
```

...`this` within `Rectangle` will refer to a *new object* created by the `new` operator.

Re Example 2:

```
this = new Rectangle(w, h);
```

You can't assign to `this`. `this` is set by how a function is called, and cannot be changed during the function's processing.

Specifically, the

```
Rectangle.call(this, w, h);
```

idiom is used when creating hierarchies to ensure that the freshly-created object has been initialized with `Rectangle` things, presumably because the current constructor (`DepthRectangle` in your case) wants to re-use that functionality.

Comment: I'm going upvote you just based on the fact that you're T.J. Crowder.

Comment: @Robert: That's odd. I've had the *opposite* reaction, but don't recall it going *this* way before. ;-)

Comment: +1 - oops, should have been -1 so you feel more comfortable... ;-p